# How to append check box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I add checkbox after  span in below code.

```
var aaa = $('<a/>')
.html("<span>"  "</span >" + " <span>""</span> ")                       
.attr('data-transition', 'slide') 
.appendTo(li);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.html()` has several issues with concatenation:

```
.html("<span>"  "</span >" + " <span>""</span> ")    
     //------^^^^--------------------^^--------useless quotes are here.
```

this way:

```
.html("<span></span ><input type='checkbox' value='' />" + " <span>""</span> ")
```

this way:

```
 .html("<span></span >" + " <span></span><input type='checkbox' value='' />")
```

or after both:

```
.html("<span></span> <input type='checkbox' value='' />" + " <span></span><input type='checkbox' value='' />")
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the html tag for checkbox inside `<span>`
try this

```
 .html("<span> <input type='checkbox' value='value' />test<input type='checkbox' value='value1' />test1</span >") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the `html` option.

```
var $a = $("<a/>", {
  "data-transition": "slide",
  "html": $("<input>", {
    "type": "checkbox"
  })
})
.appendTo(li);
```

It will render this HTML:

```
<a data-transition="slide"><input type="checkbox"></a>
```